# Entity Framework vs Nhibernate

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am using Nhibernate from about 3 years.Currently Microsoft published Asp.net Identity 2 sample using EntityFramework.But I can't customize Asp.net Identity sample with Nhibernate 4.For this reason i can't get any data by userid.So Which one i should use for my project Nhibernate or Entity Framework 6

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity)?

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this today. Looks like NHibernate has published a ASP.NET Identity Provider [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity).

You can also pull down the NuGet package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/).